# Spark/Neo4j throws error: RuntimeException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, geospatial, neo4j-spatial

The exact query:

```
call spatial.bbox('geom', {lat:37.5,lon:43.4}, {lat:37.6,lon:43.5}) yield node return node.altitude as altitude, node.detect_type as detect_type, node.gtype as gtype, node.toDateFormatLong as toDateFormatLong, node.change_area as change_area, node.latitude as latitude, node.longitude as longitude, node.fromDateFormatLong as fromDateFormatLong, node.iids as iids, node.detect_strength as detect_strength, node.fromDate as fromDate, node.bbox as bbox ORDER BY node.toDateFormatLong DESC
```

Example data set:

```
╒══════════╤═════════════╤═══════╤══════════════════╤═════════════╤══════════╤═══════════╤════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═════════════════╤══════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"altitude"│"detect_type"│"gtype"│"toDateFormatLong"│"change_area"│"latitude"│"longitude"│"fromDateFormatLong"│"iids"                                                               │"detect_strength"│"fromDate"│"bbox"                                       │
╞══════════╪═════════════╪═══════╪══════════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│-1        │"Arrival"    │1      │20161104          │16981        │37.5608649│43.4297988 │20161023            │"23OCT16S1A89377_09_IW1_09_pp_1231_04NOV16S1A90776_09_123_31_TT_QQQQ”│7.2              │"23OCT16" │[43.4297988,37.5608649,43.4297988,37.5608649]│
├──────────┼─────────────┼───────┼──────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│-1        │"Arrival"    │1      │20161104          │3123         │37.56749  │43.4807208 │20161023            │"23OCT16S1A89377_09_IW1_09_pp_1231_04NOV16S1A90776_09_124_32_TT_QQQQ"│7.5              │"23OCT16" │[43.4807208,37.56749,43.4807208,37.56749]    │
├──────────┼─────────────┼───────┼──────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

that I call

```
try {
 val initialDf2 = neo.cypher(query).loadDataFrame
 val someVal = initialDf2.collectAsList()
} catch {
   case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
}
```

I get this error:

```
 17/09/18 08:44:48 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 298.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 298.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 298.0 (TID 298, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList is not a valid external type for schema of string
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, altitude), DoubleType) AS altitude#1678
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, detect_type), StringType), true) AS detect_type#1679
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, gtype), LongType) AS gtype#1680L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 3, toDateFormatLong), LongType) AS toDateFormatLong#1681L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 4, change_area), LongType) AS change_area#1682L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 5, latitude), DoubleType) AS latitude#1683
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 6, longitude), DoubleType) AS longitude#1684
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 7, fromDateFormatLong), LongType) AS fromDateFormatLong#1685L
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 8, iids), StringType), true) AS iids#1686
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 9, detect_strength), DoubleType) AS detect_strength#1687
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 10, fromDate), StringType), true) AS fromDate#1688
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 11, bbox), StringType), true) AS bbox#1689
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkSession.scala:573)
```

Data comes back if I don't include the bbox.

In the neo4j browser, I can run the problem query and the results come back:

```
-1  “Detected”  1   20161104    3318    37.5049815  43.4171031  20161023     “filename.val” 9.2 "23OCT16"   [43.4171031, 37.5049815, 43.4171031, 37.5049815]
```

It is that secondary list, I might have to return node.bbox.somevalue1 as bbbox1, but no idea what the exact syntax would be....

I think this is a similar issue to what I was having...

[Neo4j spark connector loadDataFrame gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889198/neo4j-spark-connector-loaddataframe-gives-error)

and solved by:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/issues/40

It just seems like it wants more from what I am returning.

Comment: Can you share a sample data set and the exact query you are running? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the orignal post add that stuff first hand now.

Comment: I should add I can take out the bbox return and the query comes back (though I have no idea how to get data out of the dataframe as strings/ints etc that i can use)

Comment: Do i need more information?

Comment: any luck solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Array properties are not yet supported by the connector according to the maintainers (see https://neo4j-users.slack.com/archives/C0N7LHVS9/p1534429756000100)

There are two workarounds:

1. Use UNWIND in the query and then collect it back on spark
2. Convert the array to a string using a REDUCE operation

I prefer the 2nd approach but I am not sure how well it scales with big data.

So your query would look something like:

```
RETURN REDUCE(s = HEAD(bbox), n IN TAIL(bbox) | s + ', ' + n) AS bbox,
```

And the code that processes it:

```
neo4j.cypher(QUERY).as[String].map(bbox => bbox.split(', ')
```

Answer (score -1):

loadDataFrame  you need  decleard  the dataframe schema with the ( fieldName and  fieldtype )

like this:

```
     val rawGraphnode=neo.cypher("MATCH (n:person)where (n.duration <>0) RETURN  n.user as user,n.other as other,n.direction as direction,n.duration as duration,n.timestamp as  timestamp")
            .loadDataFrame(schema = ("user","object"),("other","object"),("direction","string"),("duration","String"),("timestamp","String"))

    rawGraphnode.printSchema()
    rawGraphnode.show(10)
```